# Cohomology ring of special linear group over finite fields

Tags: cohomology, group-cohomology, classical-groups

I am trying to find about the cohomology ring $H^*(SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ where $q$ is odd. For $n=2$, an explicit description is given. But for $n>2$, I didn't come across a thing.

If not the cohomology ring, then a description of some cohomology groups will also be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean group cohomology? Then $$H^1({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})={\rm Hom}({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}),$$ which is, I think, trivial except for some small values of $n$ and $q$.

Comment: For general linear groups instead of special linear groups, this is a famous computation of Quillen, "On the Cohomology and K-Theory of the General Linear Groups Over a Finite Field."

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathematik.ur.de/hoyois/SS20/ktheory/Quillen%20ICM%201970.pdf) is Quillen's 1970 ICM address, 5 pages. In part 1, he computes the mod p cohomology of every finite group modulo nilpotent elements. Another approx strategy is to pull back the Sylow subgroup, which is the normalizer of the torus. These probably combine to compute it exactly for $SL_n$. In part 2, he computes the coprime cohomology of the finite points of every algebraic group. For the multiplicative structure and $Z/2$ coeff, something goes wrong, but you can probably control it by comparing $SL_n$ with $GL_n$.